# Voltage across inductor

Tags: voltage, current, inductor

What is the voltage across an inductor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKGEyP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is it Ldi/dt or -Ldi/dt? I am asking this because internet has confused me assume the RL step response of the above circuit:
Since current starts rising from low values to high values it makes sense to think the voltage across L1 to have the same polarity with V1 because something has to prevent the current to go from 0 to V1/R1 at the beginning and for some time so it should be -L1di/dt but the expression of current is derived if we take VL1>0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQxmxu.png)</sup>

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DutVZLUvPZc

Comment: It depends on your sign convention. Also, please note that V(t) = Vo + Ldi/dt where Vo is the initial voltage. Only if you assume the initial voltage across the inductor is 0 do you get V(t) = Ldi/dt or -Ldi/dt.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the +/- convention you are using is consistent with your current direction convention.

With KVL and KCL you are free to decide the orientation of your voltage and current measurements for each component.

With the current direction pointing from + to - the formula is \$V = L\frac{dI}{dt}\$.

If the current orientation is pointing from - to + you introduce a minus sign.

Here's my way of remembering it...

Recall the orientation of a flyback diode to snub the high voltage arising when current through a relay coil is abruptly interrupted:

[image]

When you energize the coil current flows from A to B. When you stop that current a high voltage develops on B relative to A and the diode conducts. This means \$B-A\$ is positive when \$dI/dt\$ is negative. This is equivalent to \$A-B\$ is positive when \$dI/dt\$ is positive.